# How to add an image in a CSV file

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, xctest, xcuitest

I am writing an XCUItest and taking a screenshot of the final screen. I am saving all the result in a CSV file. Using Jenkins I am sending that CSV file as a mail.

How can I add the screenshot in my CSV file, right now I have saved the screenshot in my local device but not able to save it in a CSV file?

```
XCUIScreenshot* Screenshot = XCUIScreen.mainScreen.screenshot;
    UIImage *image = Screenshot.image;
    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSData *myImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    [fileManager createFileAtPath:@"filelocation/myimage.png" contents:myImageData attributes:nil];
```

Comment: Without resorting to some weird custom encoding scheme for your image, you can't. CSV = comma separated values. It's usually just a textual representation of spreadsheet data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can send the image in csv file. So you can change your approach by storing the screen shots (may be for few days) on web server and send the url of image as value in CSV or Alternately, as multiple attachments to the email with image file names as references in CSV